# Proof by deduction - implications

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, fake-proofs

Currently trying to explain some maths to a friend.

He has taken a statement $x^2 + 4 > 2x$ and tried to prove this is true for all $x$.

His proof is $x^2+4>2x \Rightarrow x^2-2x + 4 > 0 \Rightarrow (x-1)^2 + 3 > 0$ which is true so the original statement is true.

However this starts at the wrong place and the implication goes in the wrong direction. So I think it’s wrong and I can’t seem to convince him of this or find some basic examples to illustrate the point that statement X $\rightarrow$ true statement doesn’t mean that X is true....

So can anyone explain to me why it’s wrong using some basic counterexamples perhaps so I can have the knowledge to explain why it is wrong...

Thanks

Comment: The proof should demonstrate that the last statement implies the first *and* that the last is true, therefore concluding that the first will be true. However, those implication arrows are actualy are equivalences, so that is done.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Yes I know, but they’re left out so it’s not correct in proving the statement. I am just looking for example that if statement X gives a true statement then X is not true

Comment: Indeed, $X\to \top$ does not entail that $X$ is true. However, those arrows should be flipped, and $X\gets \top$ does entail that $X$ is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your friend is correct, the subtlety is that all his steps are reversible, so a clear way to put it is as: 
$$
x²+4>2 \iff x²-2x+4>0 \iff (x-1)²+3>0
$$
This way the truthiness of the last statement implies the same for the first.
But you are correct to be cautious, a case where things would go wrong is with squares. For example:
$$
x=1 \Rightarrow x² = 1 \Rightarrow x=1~\text{or}~x =-1
$$
The last sentence is true if $x=-1$, but the first would be false.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I know that his steps are reversible and you can just place iff symbols, but without them, it is wrong right? It's like if you want to prove $a^2 + b^2 > 2ab$, you don't go $a^2 - 2ab + b^2 \geq 0$, which gives $(a-b)^2 \geq 0$, so statement is true, you either put iff symbols there or start at $(a-b)^2 \geq 0$?

Comment: Exactly. The proof as given was incorrect, but easily correctable. @PhysicsMathLover

Answer (score 1):

Yes the fact is that the following chain

$$x^2+4>2x \Rightarrow x^2-2x + 4 > 0 \Rightarrow (x-1)^2 + 3 > 0$$

is true and it can be useful to guess a way for the proof which requires the following

$$(x-1)^2 + 3 > 0 \Rightarrow x^2-2x + 4 > 0 \Rightarrow x^2+4>2x $$

or in a more direct way we can use

$$x^2+4>2x \iff x^2-2x + 4 > 0 \iff (x-1)^2 + 3 > 0$$